# Python: XY density plot

Tags: python, oop, cartesian-coordinates

I have a data file with the following fields:

```
Index    X.coor     Y.coor    Status    Height   Census
1        197.10001  456.89999 1         696      1
2        84.20000   74.80000  0         356      1
3        282.70001  177.50000 1         439      1
...
999      427.70001  418.10001 0         543      1
```

These indices represent points on a geographic Cartesian X-Y Grid like this:

[image]

I want to plot the points in a hypothetical space (object-oriented) and divide the map into dimensions that I specify. For example, the grid above has dimensions of 7x7. Then I want to loop through each square on the Cartesian Grid and calculate the density of the points in that region.

```
Density = number of points in square / area of the square
```

The points location on the Cartesian map are fixed. The area of the squares will be different depending on the dimension that I divide the Cartesian X-Y grid. Are you aware of any Python modules that will allow me to do this? I want to do this with OOP so that I can keep track of the other attributes of each point in the squares.

I think one way I can do this is to get the maximum and minimum of the X coordinate and Y coordinates. This will give me 4 data points which I can use to form a rectangle and compute the area. Then I write a function that divides the rectangle into X by Y subregions. So far example, if I want a 8 by 16 grid, I divide the length of the rectangle by 6 and divide the width by 16 to get different sized squares. Finally I write a loop to calculate the density of each region of the Cartesian Grid. I can store the density of each region in a matrix.

Is there a Python module that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look to NumPy's [histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) and use it as

```
import numpy as np
np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(nx,ny), normed=True)
```

where `nx = ny = 7` in your demonstration case.

For an example with randomly-distributed `x,y` coordinates:

```
x = np.random.random(1000)
y = np.random.random(1000)
nx, ny = 7, 7
H, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(nx,ny), normed=True)
pylab.imshow(H, interpolation='nearest')
pylab.colorbar()
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In my original post I wanted to calculate the density of the points in each cell of the grid and store them in a matrix so that I could later output them to a file. I figured it out doing the approach I suggested. The answer you gave is a great supplement and visualization for that data.